# python - Adding a new column(Pandas Dataframe) into Postgresql Table

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dataframe

How can i dynamically create new column in exisitng postgresql database table and populate Pandas Dataframe into it ?

Till i have used:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine=create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres@localhost:5432/db_name')

df.to_sql('table_name', engine,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

where df = already created panda dataframe

Also i have two columns in Dataframe and i want to make separate columns for them in database table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what do you want to do with your Dataframe's  columns? Do you want to create new column on an existing Postgresql Table from your dataframe?

Comment: yes exactly new column in existing postgresql table

Comment: You can use `if_exists='replace'` to delete the table and create new with the pandas columns. I am wondering what will happen if we include the dummy column names which exists in db and add them to pandas.